# Gnuplot splot two real matrix using two binary matrix as indicator

Tags: matrix, binary, gnuplot

everyone.

I have 10*10 image grids, and its value is stored in two 10*10 real matrix X and Y. I want to parition my image into two parts, so I have two binary indicator matrix A, B indicating which partition does an image point belongs to, let's assume A stands for partition 1 and B stands for partition 2.

A(0,0)=1 means point (0,0) is in partition 1, and its value is stored in X(0,0), and B(0,0)=1 means point (0,0) is in partition 2, and its value is stored in Y(0,0).

And if A(0,0)=1, we have B(0,0)=0, means every image point can only belong to one partition. So, matrix A and B are exclusive, and we have A+B= matrix with all 1's.

Now, I want to splot my image grid into a 3-D graph, so x and y axis are just from 0 to 9, with z values store in matrix X and Y. But I need to also include binary matrix A and B to tell Gnuplot which value to use when ploting an image poit (i,j). Here, if A(i,j)=1, then I use X(i,j) as its z value. Otherwise, I use Y(i,j).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that gnuplot basically processes data files with data in columns *row-by-row*. It can do calculation on data values quite solely on single rows. 
Doing calculations with values stored in different files is impossible.

Gnuplot also  is not a computer algebra system nor has it enough abilities to program something.

So, how is your data stored? It would be best to have a single file with rows

```
x-coord  y-coord  X-value  Y-value  A-value   B-value
```

Then, you can use this in gnuplot:

```
splot "MydataFile" using 1:2:($5==1?$3:$4)
```

If you add a blank line after every 10 rows in your file (to separate each "pixel line" of the pictures), you may also find useful

```
plot "MydataFile" using 1:2:($5==1?$3:$4) with image
```

as its output is more like an image.

**Explanation:**

```
($5==1?$3:$4)
```

means: If the value in column 5 is equal to 1, then use the value of column 3, else of column 4.   (OK, we do'nt need matrix B here, because A contains all information you need)